# Codeigniter Sessions Swapped - Mixed Between Users

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

the issue i am facing, is that user sessions are getting swapped when to user are with same id are logged in the system.
Fore example if i login as 2 different user one in Chrome and second in Firefox,
and start refreshing pages at same time in one browser session will be forgotten and i will get a session id from other browser,

But if i don't refresh in same time this will not happen,
if i tray this with localhost on WAMP server, this problem does not appear.

i appreciate any suggestions, how to debug, or how to fix the problem

Comment: Is this happens on a localhost or live server?

Comment: This is happens on live server.

Comment: I have encountered similar weird session behaviour and in my case it turns out that it happens on a shared hosting, and it has something to do with the way shared hosting store sessions.

Comment: In my case switching to non-shared actually solves the issue, but since I am planning to using a shared hosting, I overcome this by turning on the csrf protection, so each user session will have unique id on them and no more random swap

Comment: sistem is on WHM  sistem,  i enabled csrf Protection,  but no use, i will continue to tray to find solution,  thanks a lot Hasta,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was created by **Engintron**, this cache session and when 2 users refresh same page at same time, sessions ids get mixed up

Comment: Is anyone have a solution how to live Engintron enabled, but to prevent this behavior

Answer (score 1):

The problem can also be solved by disabling micro caching in Engintron, no need to disable the entire plugin and at least you can still use static file caching.

Head to WHM -> Engintron for cPanel/WHM -> Edit your custom_rules for Nginx

At the bottom add:

```
if ($SITE_URI ~* "yoursite.tld") {
   set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1; # Disables micro-caching
}
```

Hit 'Update /etc/nginx/custom_rules'